# Inicio de sesión Django

Tags: python, django

Actualmente tengo un inicio de sesión en Django que redirige al usuario al panel de control de mi web mediante:

```
render(request,'panel.html')
```

Pero desde el `views.py` de la app `panel` no sé acceder a los datos del usuario que ha iniciado sesión para mostrarlos.

¿Cómo obtengo desde **panel.html** el objeto usuario que ha iniciado sesión?

mi código de **views.py**:

```
elif 'logInButton' in request.POST:
    if login_email and login_password:
        try:
            user = Usuario.objects.get(email=login_email)
            #compare hashed: bcrypt.hashpw(input, self.password) == self.password:
        except Exception as e:
            messages.error(request, 'Error in user or password')
            return redirect('home')
        if str(bcrypt.hashpw(login_password.encode('utf-8'), user.password[2:len(user.password)-1].encode('utf-8'))) == user.password:
            if not user.activated:
                messages.warning(request, 'You must to activate your user!')
                return redirect('home')
            user.last_login = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
            fingerprint = request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT')+request.META.get('COMPUTERNAME')+request.META.get('OS')
            ip = str(request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR'))
            old_ip_and_old_fingerprint = (sha3.sha3_224(str(fingerprint).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() == user.fingerprint) and (ip in user.ip)
            if (not old_ip_and_old_fingerprint) and user.two_factors_auth: 
                # doble_auth_send()
                messages.debug('doble_auth')
                return redirect('home')
            elif not old_ip_and_old_fingerprint: 
                notify_new_conection(ip,user.name,ip,request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT'),request.META.get('COMPUTERNAME'),request.META.get('OS'),user.email) #notificamos la posible intrusion
                user.ip = user.ip+ip+'|'
                user.fingerprint = sha3.sha3_224(str(fingerprint).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
                user.last_login = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
                return render(request, 'dashboard.html')
            else:
                if not ip in user.ip:
                    user.ip = user.ip+ip+'|'
                if not sha3.sha3_224(str(fingerprint).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() == user.fingerprint:
                    user.fingerprint = sha3.sha3_224(str(fingerprint).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
                user.last_login = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
                return render(request, 'dashboard.html')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Error in user or password')
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        messages.warning(request, 'Make sure all fields are entered and valid')
        return redirect('home')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes tener acecso al usuario logueado a través del [`request.user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user). Por lo tanto, desde tu template puedes hacer cosas como:

```
{{request.user}}
{{request.user.id}}
```

Te preguntarás cómo se tiene acceso al usuario, ¿magia de Django? Simplemente es el middleware el que se encarga de pasarlo a todas las peticiones. En este caso el encargado es el [`AuthenticationMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware):

> *class AuthenticationMiddleware*
>
> Adds the user attribute, representing the currently-logged-in user, to every incoming HttpRequest object. See Authentication in Web requests.

En pocas palabras, agrega el atributo `user` que representa al usuario que está logueado.

Comment: Gracias, esta tarde lo pruebo y si funciona valido la respuesta!

Comment: No me funciona, desde una app hago un render al html de otra app pasándole el request como parámetro y si pongo esto: {{request.user.name}} no muestra nada. 
He analizado los parámetros de la respuesta html y me devuelve:
csrfmiddlewaretoken: l8iSQwLfh6McOqNEXSpQDMtuilkDyJInByGb6W6U8m6XXuuGtCrbOSH4jkPrf6PU
login-email: email@gmail.com
login-password: 1234
logInButton: 

Por lo que no está el usuario... con esos datos puedo sacar el usuario, por supuesto, pero no sería lo ideal. ¿Qué hago mal? He editado mi pregunta para añadir mi views.py